# How to add multiple dynamic params at laravel routes?

Tags: laravel, routes

I wanna add dynamic params using laravel routes but with multiple passing parameters like

```
Route::get('image/{folder}/{folder1}/{folder2}/{file}', function(..$folder, $image) {
//
})
```

the depth of folder is dynamic if the file found in folder 1 then return the folder 1 if the file found in folder 2 then return the file in folder 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't have other options you could make a catchall then parse the string of the rest of the url yourself:

```
Route::get('image/{all}', function ($all) {
    // parse $all to get folders and file
})->where('all', '.*');
```

You could adjust the regex pattern to be more specific potentially.

[Laravel 6 Docs - Routing - Route Parameters - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: Thank you. i didnt think about it before.